# Uploading a file with FormData and multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, drag-and-drop, multer

I have successfully managed to upload a file to a Node server using the `multer` module by selecting the file using the input file dialog and then by submitting the form, but now I would need, instead of submitting the form, to create a `FormData` object, and send the file using `XMLHttpRequest`, but it isn't working, the file is always `undefined` at the server-side (router).

The function that does the AJAX request is:

```
function uploadFile(fileToUpload, url) {

  var form_data = new FormData();

  form_data.append('track', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

  // This function simply creates an XMLHttpRequest object
  // Opens the connection and sends form_data
  doJSONRequest("POST", "/tracks/upload", null, form_data, function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  })

}
```

Note that `fileToUpload` is defined and the `url` is correct, since the correct router method is called. `fileToUpload` is a `File` object obtained by dropping a file from the filesystem to a dropzone, and then by accessing the `dataTransfer` property of the drop event.

`doJSONRequest` is a function that creates a `XMLHttpRequest` object and sends the file, etc (as explained in the comments).

```
function doJSONRequest(method, url, headers, data, callback){

  //all the arguments are mandatory
  if(arguments.length != 5) {
    throw new Error('Illegal argument count');
  }

  doRequestChecks(method, true, data);

  //create an ajax request
  var r = new XMLHttpRequest();

  //open a connection to the server using method on the url API
  r.open(method, url, true);

  //set the headers
  doRequestSetHeaders(r, method, headers);

  //wait for the response from the server
  r.onreadystatechange = function () {
    //correctly handle the errors based on the HTTP status returned by the called API
    if (r.readyState != 4 || (r.status != 200 && r.status != 201 && r.status != 204)){
      return;
    } else {
      if(isJSON(r.responseText))
        callback(JSON.parse(r.responseText));
      else if (callback !== null)
        callback();
    }
  };

  //set the data
  var dataToSend = null;
  if (!("undefined" == typeof data) 
    && !(data === null))
    dataToSend = JSON.stringify(data);

  //console.log(dataToSend)

  //send the request to the server
  r.send(dataToSend);
}
```

And here's `doRequestSetHeaders`:

```
function doRequestSetHeaders(r, method, headers){

  //set the default JSON header according to the method parameter
  r.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");

  if(method === "POST" || method === "PUT"){
    r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  }

  //set the additional headers
  if (!("undefined" == typeof headers) 
    && !(headers === null)){

    for(header in headers){
      //console.log("Set: " + header + ': '+ headers[header]);
      r.setRequestHeader(header, headers[header]);
    }

  }
}
```

and my router to upload files is the as follows

```
// Code to manage upload of tracks
var multer = require('multer');
var uploadFolder = path.resolve(__dirname, "../../public/tracks_folder");

function validTrackFormat(trackMimeType) {
  // we could possibly accept other mimetypes...
  var mimetypes = ["audio/mp3"];
  return mimetypes.indexOf(trackMimeType) > -1;
}

function trackFileFilter(req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, validTrackFormat(file.mimetype));
}

var trackStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  // used to determine within which folder the uploaded files should be stored.
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {

    callback(null, uploadFolder);
  },

  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    // req.body.name should contain the name of track
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: trackStorage,
  fileFilter: trackFileFilter
});


router.post('/upload', upload.single("track"), function(req, res) {
  console.log("Uploaded file: ", req.file); // Now it gives me undefined using Ajax!
  res.redirect("/"); // or /#trackuploader
});
```

My guess is that `multer` is not understanding that `fileToUpload` is a file with name `track` (isn't it?), i.e. the middleware `upload.single("track")` is not working/parsing properly or nothing, or maybe it simply does not work with `FormData`, in that case it would be a mess. What would be the alternatives by keeping using multer?

How can I upload a file using AJAX and multer?

Don't hesitate to ask if you need more details.

Comment: Hi , Try this .http://jasonshultz.com/blog/file-upload-with-angularjs-node-and-express

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) uses `multipart/form-data` content-type requests for uploading files. Removing this bit from your `doRequestSetHeaders` function should fix your problem:

```
if(method === "POST" || method === "PUT"){
   r.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
}
```

You don't need to specify the `content-type` since `FormData` objects already use the right encoding type. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects):

> The transmitted data is in the same format that the form's submit()
>   method would use to send the data if the form's encoding type were set
>   to multipart/form-data.

Here's a working example. It assumes there's a dropzone with the id `drop-zone` and an upload button with an id of `upload-button`:

```
var dropArea  = document.getElementById("drop-zone");
var uploadBtn = document.getElementById("upload-button");
var files     = [];

uploadBtn.disabled = true;
uploadBtn.addEventListener("click", onUploadClick, false);

dropArea.addEventListener("dragenter", prevent, false);
dropArea.addEventListener("dragover",  prevent, false);
dropArea.addEventListener("drop", onFilesDropped, false);   

//----------------------------------------------------
function prevent(e){

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
}

//----------------------------------------------------
function onFilesDropped(e){

    prevent(e);

    files = e.dataTransfer.files;

    if (files.length){
        uploadBtn.disabled = false;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------
function onUploadClick(e){

    if (files.length){
        sendFile(files[0]);
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------
function sendFile(file){

    var formData = new FormData();
    var xhr      = new XMLHttpRequest();

    formData.append("track", file, file.name);

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/tracks/upload", true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {  
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {  
            if (xhr.status === 200) {  
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            } else {  
                console.error(xhr.statusText);  
            }  
        }  
    };

    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

The server side code is a simple express app with the exact router code you provided.

Comment: Did I say that my form is multipart, i.e. I have other type of fields in my form..?

Comment: I'm not sure sure i understand your question? "content-type" for that request is set to "'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary...", as expected. Otherwise multer wouldn't even work with it in the first place. You can add further fields using formData.append and read them from req.body.

Comment: I haven't tried your code yet, but it really seems similar to mine, so I don't see why yours should work... could you please explain why should that work?

Comment: To answer that question you should either post your complete client side code (not just uploadFile) or try mine. Mine does, again, work. Tested with your exact router code.

Comment: I will post my `doJSONRequest` method implementation...See edit now.

Comment: Are you setting content-type manually in doRequestSetHeaders? That'd be one difference to my code and why mine works and yours doesn't.

Comment: Yes, I will also post the implementation of that function, if you want..see edit.

Comment: Well, that is the reason why your code isn't working and mine isn't. Let's move this to a chat, though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97312/discussion-between-cviejo-and-nbro).

Answer (score 2):

to post a FormData object accepted by multer the upload function should be like this:

```js
function uploadFile(fileToUpload, url) { 
    var formData = new FormData();
    //append file here 
    formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    //and append the other fields as an object here
    /* var user = {name: 'name from the form',
        email: 'email from the form' 
        etc...       
    }*/
    formData.append('user', user);

    // This function simply creates an XMLHttpRequest object
    // Opens the connection and sends form_data
    doJSONRequest("POST", "/tracks/upload", null, formData, function(d) {
        console.log(d);
    })
}
```